# Dynamic CRM 2016 how to filter document templates based on related entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have many Document templates for several Entities. when user is on particular entity, and on click of a custom button, I want to show only the Entity's related Document Template names as radio buttons to choose one to generate a document  i.e. when user is on Contact entity, the user should be listed only Document templates which are related to Contact Entity. I am looking for Dialog process to do this.

Please suggest a way to do filter the Document templates.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is Possible with custom html pages created in webresource & pulling the data with SDK calls in JS. Needs huge efforts.